# for-loop in shell between hosts (with ssh)

Tags: shell, ssh

I have a for loop to go through my other amazon instances:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST="ec2xxxA.compute.amazonaws.com ec2xxxB-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
SSHKEY="ssh -tt -i key.pem centos@"

  for i in $LIST; do
    ${SSHKEY}$i hostname
```

Now I try to loop through my list and print the hostname of the 2 instances of amazon.
It works for the first one. But after the loop it doesn't go further:.

```
./script.sh
ip-172-xx-xx-01
Connection to ec2-xxxA-1.compute.amazonaws.com closed.
Last login: Thu Jan 28 14:09:48 2016 from ip-172-xx-xx-01.compute.internal
[centos@ip-172-xx-xx-01 ~]$
```

So as you can see it's telling me it closed the connection but after closing the connection the prompt shows the IP of the host again.
I have to type `exit` and after it, it goes further to the following host (which I also have to exit).

Adding `exit` in the script did not help. Then it's just stopping everything after the first host.

Comment: Why do you have the `-tt` option, if you are just trying to run `hostname` and return back?

Comment: later on I will need to perform commands as root

Comment: Where does that first `ip-...` line come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `-tt` option from your command.

Comment: i have a similar command that uses -t -t and it works fine. Why would -tt break it?

Comment: It shouldn't, but it might. Check [this](http://serverfault.com/a/593419/274648) answer.

Comment: So, I understand that you want to print the hostname of every instance and then stay connected to execute other commands right? If that's the case, you should use `${SSHKEY}$i "hostname; bash"` .